# Recursive key search in JsonElement does not return value

Tags: java, json, recursion

I am facing a problem with a relatively simple recursive function, I adapted from [Find value for a key from a dynamic json using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157781/find-value-for-a-key-from-a-dynamic-json-using-java). The function consists of searching for a key (arg1) in a nested JsonElement (arg2) and if the key is matched in the input, returning its corresponding value. The original method consisted of a void method that would have stored the value(s) in a static list but I need to change the method to return a String.

The problem I am facing is that, although the algorithm manages to search recursively within the structure of the JSON when it finds the right key and returns its value, it does not actually exit the method due to the recursive calling of the method itself. This is explained in this link: [Java Return not exiting method (loops)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727019/java-return-not-exiting-method-loops). Hence, the method always returns a "No value" string.

I have tried different tactics to solve this but unsuccessfully.

Can I please ask your help to solve this?

````
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Utils {
    
    public Utils() {}
    
    public String searchJson(String key, JsonElement jsonElement) {
        
        String value = "No value";
        
        // If input is an array, iterate through each element
        if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
            for (JsonElement jsonElement1 : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
                searchJson(key, jsonElement1);
            }
        }
        
        else {
            
            // If input is object, iterate through the keys
            if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonElement
                        .getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
                    
                    // If key corresponds to the 
                    String key1 = entry.getKey();
                    if (key1.equals(key)) {
                        value = entry.getValue().toString();
                        return value;
                    }
                    
                    // Use the entry as input, recursively
                    searchJson(key, entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            
            // If input is element, check whether it corresponds to the key
            else {
                if (jsonElement.toString().equals(key)) {
                    value = jsonElement.toString();
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        
        // Create JSON response
        String response = "{\"jsonData\":[{\"cards\":[{\"card\":\"MTE14019797\",\"Explanation\":{\"Message\":\"No explaination key identified\",\"Status\":\"Failed\"},\"Prediction\":{\"Confidence_intervals\":[{\"confidence\":\"0.614\",\"distance\":\"0.3\",\"range_lower\":\"1.117\",\"range_upper\":\"1.717\"}],\"Message\":\"\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"point_estimate\":\"1.417\"}},{\"card\":\"MTE14019798\",\"Explanation\":{\"Message\":\"No explaination key identified\",\"Status\":\"Failed\"},\"Prediction\":{\"Confidence_intervals\":[{\"confidence\":\"0.584\",\"distance\":\"0.3\",\"range_lower\":\"1.852\",\"range_upper\":\"2.452\"}],\"Message\":\"\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"point_estimate\":\"2.152\"}}],\"Status\":\"Success\",\"modelTarget\":\"MTEter\",\"modelType\":\"conformalRegression\",\"modelUpdated\":\"2020-09-01\",\"principalResults\":[\"point_estimate\",\"confidence\",\"distance\",\"modelUpdated\"]}]}\r\n";
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json = parser.parse(response.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
        
        System.out.println(json.toString());
        System.out.println();
        
        // Access card response
        JsonArray cardResponse = json.get("jsonData").getAsJsonArray()
                .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
                .get("cards").getAsJsonArray();
        
        // Iterate through individual responses
        Iterator<JsonElement> cardIter = cardResponse.iterator();
        
        while (cardIter.hasNext()) {
            
            // Select next card
            JsonObject card = cardIter.next().getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(card);
            
            String key = "Status";
            
            // TODO: Replace with variable from map
            // If selected card Id corresponds to that in the iterator, 
            // then search for the value associated to the selected end-point 
            String cardId = card.get("card").getAsString();
            if (cardId.equals("MTE14019798")) {
                String value = utils.searchJson(key, card);
                System.out.print(value);
            }
        }
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: post the sample input and expected ouput and also explain how your code different from the expected output. and also don't post the whole code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the value in recursive calls hence it is getting lost , you can save your return value in a variable and check for null, if it's not null you have found the value and you can break from any loops and return from recursive function.

I have modified some parts, Go through it. Also, Add null checks wherever required.

```
class Utils {

public Utils() {
}

public String searchJson(String key, JsonElement jsonElement) {

    String value = null;

    // If input is an array, iterate through each element
    if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
        for (JsonElement jsonElement1 : jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()) {
            value = searchJson(key, jsonElement1);
            if (value != null) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    } else {

        // If input is object, iterate through the keys
        if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
            Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonElement
                    .getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {

                // If key corresponds to the
                String key1 = entry.getKey();
                if (key1.equals(key)) {
                    value = entry.getValue().toString();
                    return value;
                }

                // Use the entry as input, recursively
                value = searchJson(key, entry.getValue());
                if (value != null) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }

        // If input is element, check whether it corresponds to the key
        else {
            if (jsonElement.toString().equals(key)) {
                value = jsonElement.toString();
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
}

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Utils utils = new Utils();

    // Create JSON response
    String response = "{\"jsonData\":[{\"cards\":[{\"card\":\"MTE14019797\",\"Explanation\":{\"Message\":\"No explaination key identified\",\"Status\":\"Failed\"},\"Prediction\":{\"Confidence_intervals\":[{\"confidence\":\"0.614\",\"distance\":\"0.3\",\"range_lower\":\"1.117\",\"range_upper\":\"1.717\"}],\"Message\":\"\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"point_estimate\":\"1.417\"}},{\"card\":\"MTE14019798\",\"Explanation\":{\"Message\":\"No explaination key identified\",\"Status\":\"Failed\"},\"Prediction\":{\"Confidence_intervals\":[{\"confidence\":\"0.584\",\"distance\":\"0.3\",\"range_lower\":\"1.852\",\"range_upper\":\"2.452\"}],\"Message\":\"\",\"Status\":\"Success\",\"point_estimate\":\"2.152\"}}],\"Status\":\"Success\",\"modelTarget\":\"MTEter\",\"modelType\":\"conformalRegression\",\"modelUpdated\":\"2020-09-01\",\"principalResults\":[\"point_estimate\",\"confidence\",\"distance\",\"modelUpdated\"]}]}\r\n";
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject json = parser.parse(response.toString()).getAsJsonObject();

    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println();

    // Access card response
    JsonArray cardResponse = json.get("jsonData").getAsJsonArray()
            .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .get("cards").getAsJsonArray();

    // Iterate through individual responses
    Iterator<JsonElement> cardIter = cardResponse.iterator();

    while (cardIter.hasNext()) {

        // Select next card
        JsonObject card = cardIter.next().getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(card);

        String key = "Status";

        // TODO: Replace with variable from map
        // If selected card Id corresponds to that in the iterator,
        // then search for the value associated to the selected end-point
        String cardId = card.get("card").getAsString();
        if (cardId.equals("MTE14019798")) {
            String value = utils.searchJson(key, card);
            System.out.print(value);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I tried a similar thing using booleans but I did not manage to make it to work. I have also tried to add extra null checks to your snippet but it does not work either.

Comment: I ran in my system its working , its returning failed. Whats the issue

Comment: Can you edit your response and add the full, runnable code? Thank you

Comment: check now added all the code

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it works fine

Comment: then can you accept the answer?